# how can i remove an extra line from my plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot some data:

```
u1 = []

for i in range(12):
    u1.append(10)

f = [14.04, 13.31, 12.71, 11.89, 9.92, 8.53, 14.04, 14.92, 15.42, 16.14, 17.42, 20.78]

u2 = [5.8, 4.8, 3.8, 2.8, 1.8, 0.8, 5.8, 4.8, 3.8, 2.8, 1.8, 0.8]

Ku = [round(i/j, 2)*100 for i, j in zip(u2, u1)]

plt.plot(f, Ku)
plt.show()
```

When I use scatter plot everything seems to work fine:

[image: scatter plot]

However when I use plot function it adds an extra line that connects first point and a maximum point. But I need only one curve that connects these points .

[image: here is the plot I got]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to sort the x and y values.

```py
x,y = zip(*[(a,b) for a,b in sorted(zip(f,Ku))])
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the f list, which you use as your x axis, you'll see that the values are not ordered. Matplotlib just follows the line in the order of the points you give it.

You can do the following before the plotting to sort the values in the correct order:

```
import numpy as np
ord = np.flip(np.argsort(f))
f_orderd = np.array(f)[ord]
Ku_ordered =np.array(Ku)[ord]
plt.plot(f_ordered,Ku_ordered); 
plt.show()
```